# focus() function doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have some JS that shows a search modal and gives the search focus. It looks like this:

```
function searchOpen(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  searchOverlay.classList.add("show");
  searchOverlayInput.focus();
}
```

Seems to work OK in chrome and safari, but in FireFox the search does not focus.

I found:

[Javascript focus not working in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753635/javascript-focus-not-working-in-firefox)

[javascript focus() not working on Firefox and IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936770/javascript-focus-not-working-on-firefox-and-ie)

Both answers suggest 2 things

1. User specific setting
2. do a `setTimeout()`

There are no user specific settings on my iMac that would prevent this from happening. As for suggestion #2 I tried:

```
function searchOpen(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  searchOverlay.classList.add("show");
  setTimeout(function(){searchOverlayInput.focus();}, 1);
}
```

It still doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: could you provide a snippet so we can test it?

Comment: Yeah, give me one minute...

Comment: I made the fiddle but it works!? But in my actual project it doesn't....this sucks.

Comment: Probably there is something else firing the focus after this. Did you try to debug? Put a breakpoint to check if your element is focused in first place.

Comment: Do you have some that runs code on `focusin`, `focusout` or `blur` events? Firefox and Chrome emit some or all those events in different order (e.g. when focus moves from X to Y one emits X.blur, Y.focus and another does Y.focus, X.blur). Maybe you have some  *other* code that does something that messes your final state as a result of this difference.

Answer (score 1):

I run code sort of like this to see if an element is available to focus. Basically check to see if it is visible, if not, than check again, until it is able to be focused.

```js
function focusWhenVisible (elem) {
  var cnt = 0;
  var check = function () {
    if (elem.offsetHeight) {  //reports zero when hidden
      elem.focus()
    } else if (cnt++ < 1000) {  // only check for a certain amount of iterations
      setTimeout(check, 1);
    }
  }
  check()
}

document.querySelector("#b1").addEventListener("click", function () {
    var inp = document.querySelector("#in1");
    focusWhenVisible(inp)
    inp.removeAttribute("hidden");
});


document.querySelector("#b2").addEventListener("click", function () {
    var inp = document.querySelector("#in2");
    focusWhenVisible(inp)
    window.setTimeout(()=>{inp.removeAttribute("hidden");},500)
});
```

```html
<input type="input" id="in1" hidden />
<button type="button" id="b1">Click</button>


<input type="input" id="in2" hidden />
<button type="button" id="b2">Click w/ Delay</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But this example works in firefox. I copy pasted the basic markup and code from my project (where it doesn't work) but can't replicate it...I'm not sure what's going on. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this problem today too. The issue is that while Firefox *focuses* the component, it does not show the soft keyboard unless the event has been triggered from a `click` event. Notably it does not work from a `pointerdown` event for me, I did not try `touchstart`.

Use your first code snippet, and see if it behaves as expected from a button click or such.

Wrapping the call to focus() in a `setTimeout` is a no go, since it will lose the dynamic security context and fail.